# Illustrator layer doesn't show when exporting to a PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I have an Illustrator layer that when exported to a PDF, the objects in that layer are hidden when viewing in a PDF viewer. This doesn't happen when I export the image for web. All objects are simple shapes or text, no linked files.

Similar but different issue: [Placed image doesn't show when saving as PDF](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46275/placed-image-doesnt-show-when-saving-as-pdf)

Comment: Which PDF viewer?  Try using Adobe Reader.

Comment: @BillyKerr I tried using both Adobe Acrobat and Mac Previewer. Both will hide the layer if the Illustrator Layer does not have "Print" checked. I am not sure if all PDF viewers will act the same.

Comment: Then AndrewH has given you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the layer is visible for print.

1. Double-click on the layer to open the Layer Options
2. Make sure there is a checkmark next to "Print". If this option is unchecked, the layer will not be visible in a PDF viewer and will not print.

[image: Layer Options Preview]

This option is useful when adding notes to an Illustrator file but someone casually viewing the PDF does not need to see these notes.